# 127.0.0.1:8000/laravel-websockets 404 Not found

Tags: laravel, websocket

I followed the steps in installing `beyondcode/laravel-websockets` from https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/installation.

But when I tried to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/laravel-websockets, it's 404 Not found
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRgDC.png).

In my composer.json:

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "beyondcode/laravel-websockets": "^1.12",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.5",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.14",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "~3.0"
    },
```

.env file:

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=1111
PUSHER_APP_KEY=local
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=local
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=ap1
```

APP_URL in .env:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

In config/websockets.php:

```
    /*
     * This path will be used to register the necessary routes for the package.
     */
    'path' => 'laravel-websockets',
```

Did I miss something here?

Comment: You might have misunderstood `'path' => 'laravel-websockets'`, this doesn't add any routes to your app.

Comment: Okay thanks, thought it was relevant. The issue is fixed now, just restarted my pc then redo the fresh installation.

Answer (score 1):

if everything is ok, just make sure to clear the route cache
run `php artisan route:cache`